# iOS app sound only coming through headphones or when ringer not muted

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I am using in my

viewDidLoad:

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
BOOL success = [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:&setCategoryError];
if (!success) {  /**handle the error condition */ }

NSError *activationError = nil;
success = [audioSession setActive:YES error:&activationError];
if (!success) {  /**handle the error condition */  }

NSURL *SoundURL1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"music1" ofType:@"caf"]];
```

and have initialized in the interface

```
AVAudioPlayer *playSoundURL1;
```

and called in my method

```
[playSoundURL1 play];
```

Sound plays perfectly fine when I'm using headphones when ringer is silent or not silent. However, without any headphones I can only hear the sound when the ringer is not silenced.

Comment: You set the category of `AVAudioSession` to `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient`, that's why you have such issue. Here is the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionBasics/AudioSessionBasics.html) helping you choose the right category.